# PHP mySQL - Can you return an associated array with a number index?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this method in my db class

```
public function query($queryString)
    {

      if (!$this->_connected) $this->_connectToDb(); //connect to database

      $results = mysql_query($queryString, $this->_dbLink) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

      return mysql_num_rows($results) > 0 ? mysql_fetch_assoc($results) : false;            

    }
```

This works great for queries that return 1 row, but how can I get an array returned something like this?

```
$array[0]['name'] = 'jim'
$array[0]['id'] =  120
$array[1]['name'] = 'judith' 
$array[1]['ID'] = 121
```

Now I know I could use a while loop to insert this data into the array like so, but I was wondering if PHP could do this with an internal function? I havn't been able to find on the docs what I'm after.

The reason I don't want to run the while within the method is because I am going to reiterate back over the array when it's returned, and I'd rather not run through the results twice (for performance reasons).

Is there a way to do this? Do I have a problem with my general query method design?

Thank you muchly!

Comment: FWIW, this is kind of tangential but did you know that if you can call mysql_num_rows() then you already have the full result set occupying memory in your PHP process?  There's no way to know the number of rows until the app has fetched them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function query($queryString)
    {

        if (!$this->_connected) $this->_connectToDb(); //connect to database

        $results = mysql_query($queryString, $this->_dbLink) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

        $data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
         {
               $data[] = $row;
         }
        return $data;

    }
```

this will always return an array.

EDIT:
I didn't read the question well.
If you realy don't want to use the loop then I would do this:

```
public function query($queryString)
    {

        if (!$this->_connected) $this->_connectToDb(); //connect to database

        return mysql_query($queryString, $this->_dbLink) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    }
```

then loop over it, however I would just use the loop.

Comment: I'll second the suggestion to stick with the first code, it's cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to do it this way. I'm always looking for ways to refactor my code to make it as inexpensive as possible. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look at the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension. You can load the entire result set into an array or you can loop using foreach.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO($connection_string, $username, $password);
$result = $db->query($queryString);
foreach($result as $row) {
    // do something
}

// or

$result = $db->query($queryString);
$result_array = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people use a `while()` loop in the query to do exactly what you want and then loop over the array to process it.

However, you're right: it wastes memory, which could be a problem with a large dataset. An alternative is for your query method to return the resultset resource. Then your while loop can use that to fetch each row as it requires it.

To abstract that away, I would suggest another class to do that for you. Then your query call would return a new instance of that class which has the MySQL resultset resource as an instance variable and packages up the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [PEAR::MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) ([Quickstart Cheatsheet](http://codeschmie.de/archives/127-MDB2-Cheatsheet.html)). It provides lots of different functions for doing something like this. It also does not tie you down into using MySQL specific functions because it is a database abstraction layer.

$result = $db->queryRow($query, MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

There are other abstraction layers such as ADO as well.

Comment: Isn't the SQL language different for different databases?

Comment: SQL is a "standard". However most of the databases implement only certain portions of the standard (SQL95 for example). In general most of the basic query syntax will work reliably across multiple databases.

Comment: Well with my method, abstraction should be able to be done. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the ideas.  I have a function that returns an associative array from the sql (used in Moodle).

$results = get_records_sql($sql);

```
//to create a numerically indexed array:
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row)
     {
           $data[] = $row;
     }
return $data;
```

}

Comment: I'm using PDO now and it has this function built in... simply call the method fetchAll(MYSQL_ASSOC) or similiar. Check the docs.