# mysql query result into php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Some code here, I want store mysql query result into an array with php, but my code return result: `2h`, not what I wish.(the correct result should be 36,35,34,33,32)

```
<?php
set_time_limit(59);
mysql_select_db("mycoon",$db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,link FROM mytable Order By id DESC LIMIT 0,5");
$new_array[] = $row;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row;
    $new_array[$row['link']] = $row;
}
mysql_close($db);// close mysql then do other job with set_time_limit(59)
foreach($new_array as $array){
    echo $array['id'].'<br />';
    echo $array['link'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

Result:

```
36
http://localhost/img/img36.jpg
36
http://localhost/img/img36.jpg
35
http://localhost/img/img35.jpg
35
http://localhost/img/img35.jpg
34
http://localhost/img/img34.jpg
34
http://localhost/img/img34.jpg
33
http://localhost/img/img33.jpg
33
http://localhost/img/img33.jpg
32
http://localhost/img/img32.jpg
32
http://localhost/img/img32.jpg
```

Comment: Your SQL seems to be invalid: `WHERE Order By` - missing `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @hsz, right. indeed, my original code is very long, for an easy ask, I have shorted my code, but forget not remove `where`, thanks.

Comment: Dup of [Can you return an associated array with a number index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339371/), [For each result in MySQL query, push to array (complicated)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047896/) and ***many*** others (how many can we find?).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you wanted to do this:

```php
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}
```

Or maybe store id as key too

```php
 $new_array[ $row['id']] = $row;
```

Using the second ways you would be able to address rows directly by their id, such as: `$new_array[ 5]`.

Comment: @fishman I've update it. Did you use it like this, or did you put `$new_array[]` twice there?

Answer (score 4):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: It's kinda funny to see that the function that makes an array is called assoc instead array :-)

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc is deprecated since PHP 7.0: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php Use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $new_array[$row['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $new_array[$row['id']]['link'] = $row['link'];
}
```

To retrieve link and id:

```
foreach($new_array as $array)
{       
   echo $array['id'].'<br />';
   echo $array['link'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: You're not initializing `$new_array[ $row['id']]` as array. Wouldn't `$new_array[ $row['id']] = array( 'id' => $row['id'], 'link' => $row['link']);` (assuming that you WANT and need change values/keys) work faster?

Comment: $row['id'] is dynamic so in a loop, $new_array[$row['id']] looks like: $new_array[1] = '...', $new_array[2] = '...',$new_array[3] = '...' ,etc, try print_r($new_array);