# How to put sql query result into an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put a sql query result into an array.
I tried the code below but it shows the 1st record for $count times.
Obviously it's something wrong at the "$dept[$i]= $row['name'];".
But i have no idea how to fix it.
Somebody help please?

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM system_dept ORDER BY id";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $dept = array();
    $i=0;

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $dept[$i]= $row['name'];
        echo $dept[$i];
    }
}
```

Ok, i tried to use mysqli but it doesnt work.
the web server shows that:
MySQL client version: 4.1.22
PHP extension: mysql
Can mysqli works in mysql php extension?

Comment: What language? Is that PHP?

Comment: Looks like PHP. Also should probably mention that it's MySQL, too ...

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: mysql_fecth_array() gets one record at a time from $result. use  while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) to iterate through all the records

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql query result into php array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970117/mysql-query-result-into-php-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only fetching one row to fetch more rows you'll need to call fetch result again
so just add this to your code and things should be fine:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $dept[$i]= $row['name'];
        echo $dept[$i];
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
```

I would recommend using a while loop instead like the following:

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM system_dept ORDER BY id";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $dept = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $dept[]=$row['name'];
      echo $row['name'];
     }
}
```

If at all possible look into mysqli and PDO, as they are both more efficient

Answer (score 5):

Why are you only fetching one row, when you actually want all rows?

With mysqli:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db");    
$result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM system_dept ORDER BY id");    
$names = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

With PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=foo_db;dbhost=localhost', 'foo_dbo', 'pass');
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT name FROM system_dept ORDER BY id");
$names = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This leads to the same result as the other answers but without the loop! It's faster!
If you fetch row by row, you're slower but depending on what you do, you'll need less memory. If you're storing each row in an array, this will not be the case. So fetching all is the way to go.

Comment: I think someone is messing with us :)

Comment: + for using `mysqli` and `PDO`

Answer (score 3):

```
$dept = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM system_dept ORDER BY id');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $dept[] = $row['name'];
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: Thanks.This is very resourceful!~ This time for me to learn msqli now ;)

Comment: @Newbie I'd suggest PDO :)